# Running CakePHP Cron jobs on Media Temple grid service

Tags: php, cakephp, cron, mediatemple

I have the following Shell in my CakePHP app:

```
<?php 

class MyShell extends Shell {

    public function sendEmail() {

        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

        $email = new CakeEmail();

        $email->from('cameron@driz.co.uk');

        $email->to('cameron@driz.co.uk');

        $email->subject('Test Email from Cron');

        $result = $email->send('Hello from Cron');

    }

}

?>
```

Which I am trying to run every 5 minutes as a test on my Media Temple Grid Service host.

```
/home/####/domains/driz.co.uk/html/app && Console/cake my_shell send_email 

cd /home/####/domains/driz.co.uk/html && Console/cake my_shell send_email 

cd /home/####/domains/driz.co.uk/html/app && Console/cake my_shell send_email 

php /home/####/domains/driz.co.uk/html/app/Console/Command/MyShell.php
```

I have tried ALL of the above but none of them work... Any ideas why?

(Note: that the times are missing as you specify these in the admin panel separate to the actual command)

Has anyone got any experience running CakePHP cron jobs on Media Temple? I have asked MT support, and they explained that the first 3 lines wouldn't work because they are not direct commands to the files (so apparently the CakePHP docs are for the terminal only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it working:

Modified your email script to include some output:

```
class MyShell extends Shell {
    public function sendEmail() {
        App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
        $email = new CakeEmail();
        $email->from('user@domain.com');
        $email->to('user@domain.com');
        $email->subject('Test Email from Cron');
        $result = $email->send('Hello from Cron');
        $this->out('Email sent successfully.');
    }
}
```

Next, I tested via console to ensure it would work. For the above code, the "Shell" suffix in "MyShell" is omitted per the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell) and the second parameter is the function name. Here was the CLI command that worked for me from the root of the application, /home/#####/domains/mydomain.com/html/cake/cakephp/app.

```
Console/cake my sendEmail
```

Output:

```
Welcome to CakePHP v2.4.1 Console
---------------------------------------------------------------
App : app
Path: /nfs/c##/h##/mnt/#####/domains/mydomain.com/html/cake/cakephp/app/
---------------------------------------------------------------
Email sent.
```

My value in the command box in the MT (gs) dashboard was constructed according to [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html). It includes:

```
cd 'app_root' && Console/cake 'class_name_sans_shell' 'function_name'
```

For the above code, that results in:

```
cd /home/#####/domains/mydomain.com/html/cake/cakephp/app && Console/cake my sendEmail
```

It's worth noting that "Console/cake" is our executable in this case so that's the program we are running.

Comment: Whoo that worked :) What's really odd is that the MT support agent said that the above code was incorrect... :P but it works for me now! Thanks.